# how to Deploy (Publish) my Word add-in code on Amazon AWS Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, publish

I have
OS: Canonical, Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS
CPU: t2.micro [Micro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/)  with 1 GB Ram
Storage: 8 GiB

how can I publish my code on this server I am using visual studio 2022 how can I publish my add-in project code from visual studio 2022 to my Amazon AWS Server